# Able to POST request from Postman, getting Exception when Posting from client

Tags: java, okhttp, outlook-restapi

When I try to post from Post man I'm getting successful response, but when I try to do the same request from OkHttp I'm getting below Exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to outlook.office.com/13.107.18.11:443
at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:142)
at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111)
at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
at com.mindtree.service.OutlookMailer$1.intercept(OutlookMailer.java:31)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
at com.mindtree.service.OutlookMailer.getOutlookService(OutlookMailer.java:56)
at com.mindtree.controller.SendController.outlookMailSender(SendController.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LJqt.png)

```
Interceptor requestInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();
                Builder builder = original.newBuilder().header("User-Agent", "mindtreemailer")
                        // .header("client-request-id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        // .header("return-client-request-id", "true")
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .header("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", accessToken));

                Request request = builder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        };

        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        // create your json here
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("username", "yourEmail@com");
            jsonObject.put("password", "yourPassword");
            jsonObject.put("anyKey", "anyValue");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).addInterceptor(requestInterceptor).build();
        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://outlook.office.com").post(body).build();

        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String resStr = response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm not able to figure out why Its not able to connect to outlook.office.com, it's working with postman. I tried many things still not able to figure out whats the problem is.

Comment: I think you need to study what `https` is

Comment: Surely there's more to that exception / stack trace? Where is the _"caused by"_ part?